# How to use intent when using custom listview

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview

How to use different intent activity from custom `listview`.

**code**

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

    // set the icon
    actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.excel);
    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#546E7A")));

    ArrayList<Excel> list = new ArrayList<Excel>();
    list.add(new Excel("Google", "Android"));
    list.add(new Excel("Apple", "IOS"));

    ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(this, list);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.id_list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    // event handler click item of list
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View arg1,
            int position, long arg3) {
                    // call new layout with intent
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Apple.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}
}
```

the code just view Apple.class activity when i click all item, how to run different activity example:

Item Google run Google.class

Item Apple run Apple.class

Comment: use `if else ` and start appropriate activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your current code use

```
Intent intent;
if(position==0){
     intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Google.class);
}else if(position==1){
   intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Apple.class);
}
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like This

```
   listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View arg1,
            int position, long arg3) {
            switch(Position)
                {
                  case 0:
                   //Call Google Intent
                 break;
                 case 1:
                    // call new layout with intent
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Apple.class);
                 startActivity(intent);
                  break;
                default:
              // default code
               break;
              }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
    int position, long id) {
    switch( position )
    {
      case 0:  Intent newActivity = new Intent(this, Apple.class);     
             startActivity(newActivity);
             break;
      case 1:  Intent newActivity = new Intent(this, Google.class);     
              startActivity(newActivity);
             break;


    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank's very much. 

Answer (score 0):

Use reflection to get Class.The class name must be contained packagename.Like that.

```
try{
               Class classType=Class.forName("com.zfeng.stackquesimg.Google");
                Intent intent=new Intent();
                intent.setClass(MainActivity.this,classType);
                startActivity(intent);
            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```